# Solving $\int\frac{1}{\cos x}$ without knowing anything about secant!

Tags: integration, indefinite-integrals

As the title says, I am trying to solve this integral without using anything related to secant, it might sound stupid but I want to know if it can be done.

I have tried the following approach but it didn't lead me anywhere:
$$ \int\frac{1}{\cos x} = \int\frac{\sin^2 x+\cos^2 x}{cosx}$$
$$ = \int\frac{\sin^2}{\cos^2 x} +  \int\cos x$$
$$ = -\sin x + \int\frac{\sin^2 x}{\cos x} $$

Comment: What about $\log \left| \frac{1}{\cos x} + \tan x \right|+c$?

Comment: @Azif00 - that may be an answer but I think you are supposed to find a way to derive it

Comment: Every identity involving the secant function is based on those using the cosine function. I don't particularly understand your question.

Comment: $\int\frac{1}{\cos x}$ doesn't make sense. Are you integrating with respect to $x$ or with respect to another variable, for instance $t$? In the first case, Lundmark's hint below is useful. In the second case, the answer is: $\frac{t}{\cos(x)}$

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can start out like this:
$$
\int \frac{dx}{\cos x} 
= \int \frac{\cos x \, dx}{\cos^2 x} 
= \int \frac{\cos x \, dx}{1-\sin^2 x}
.
$$
Then let $u = \sin x$.

Answer (score 3):

A general rule for finding $\int\cos^n\sin^m$ that works for 3/4 of the $(n,m)\in\Bbb Z^2$: If $n$ is odd let $u=\sin$; if $m$ is odd let $u=\cos$.

That works if $n=-1$, $m=0$.

Comment: Also may work for $n$ odd integer  and $m$ real or $m$ odd integer and $n$ real.

Answer (score 1):

ΗΙΝΤ

Make the substitution $t=\tan{\frac{x}{2}}$

From this you have that $$dx=\frac{2}{1+t^2}dt$$ $$\cos{x}=\frac{1-t^2}{1+t^2}$$